# Typescript not inferring rest parameters correctly

Tags: rest, typescript, arguments, spread-syntax, inferred-type

There is a function `bar` of type `Bar`. Modified version of the function (`barStochastic`) is supposed to reset the pseudo-random generator before calling, the `bar`, but apart from that, it is identical.

Since `Bar` has many arguments, I want to pass them using `...args` spread syntax.

```ts
const random = {
    initState() {
        return 1;
    },
};
type Bar = (a: number, b: number, c: number) => number;
const barDeterministic: Bar = (a, b, c) => {
    return a + b + c;
};
const barStochastic: Bar = (...args) => {
    random.initState();
    return barDeterministic(...args);
};
```

My editor does not complain about this (it is usually consistent with TS compiler), but compilation fails.

```
error TS7019: Rest parameter 'args' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.

10     const barStochastic: Bar = (...args) => {
                                   ~~~~~~~


error TS2556: Expected 3 arguments, but got 0 or more.

12         return barDeterministic(...args);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**I would expect `...args` to be inferred as `[number, number, number]`.
That would solve both errors.**

Is this a bug or intended behavior?

---

Setup:

```
Deepin 15.7 Desktop
Node v10.9.0
tsc 2.9.2
vscode 1.27.1
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Typescript 2.9. The feature you are trying to use is [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) which was implemented in 3.0.

You can try your example in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20random%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20initState()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Bar%20%3D%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number%2C%20c%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20number%3B%0D%0Aconst%20barDeterministic%3A%20Bar%20%3D%20(a%2C%20b%2C%20c)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%20b%20%2B%20c%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20barStochastic%3A%20Bar%20%3D%20(...args)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20random.initState()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20barDeterministic(...args)%3B%0D%0A%7D) and it will work as expected.

Since your editor does not complain, my guess is your editor is using 3.0 (VS Code `1.27.1` comes with the 3.0 language service) but you compile using 2.9.